# A Simple Haskell Operator

Tags: haskell

For my assignment, we have to write a primitive function which looks like this:

My question is Prim Eq, Prim Less, Prim Great should be able to take any kinds of parameters such as String, Number although its return type is always boolean... So I am not sure how to specify the types a and b.

If you know how to approach this, please let me know. I'd really appreciate your help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: How is the `Value` type declared?

Comment: What is the complete problem statement that you are trying to solve? Is the signature `prim :: Op -> [Value] -> Value` given? By the way, i believe that `op` in the third line should really be `Op` and `Prim` in the last two lines `prim` - names in haskell are case sensitive and upper case things are either type names or constructor functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
prim Less [Number a, Number b] = Bool (a < b)
prim Less [String a, String b] = Bool (a < b)
prim Great [Number a, Number b] = Bool (a > b)
prim Great [String a, String b] = Bool (a > b)
```

`a` and `b` are not types; they're values. I'm not sure what you want to specify here.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to look at is [GADTs](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT#GADTs). However you maybe won't be able to have your `prim` function, but you can get more type safety if you could add *type signatures to constructors*, like `Eq :: Value a -> Value a -> Value Bool` and the way to do this is GADTs.

Comment: I almost downvoted; suggesting GADTs for a homework assignment for somebody who is clearly just learning Haskell seems a bit harsh. If you were implementing a language for real, I absolutely agree that this is what you would want (and this is why I didn't downvote), but this answer doesn't really seem appropriate to me for this question.

Comment: I love me my GADTs but there is nothing wrong with untyped representations of untyped languages! Sometimes a plain ADT will do what you want

Comment: @DanielWagner I agree. It was unthoughtful of me.